# Add a boolean column to a data.frame indicating wether specific columns are all NAs

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I have a `data.frame`, which has `NA`'s in several columns:

```
df <- data.frame(a0 = 1:3, a1 = c("A","B",NA), a2 = c("a",NA,NA), 
                 a3 = rep(NA,3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to add a new column, `all.na`, indicating whether columns: `c("a1","a2","a3")` are `all(is.na)`, per each row.

It can be done using `sapply`:

```
df$all.na <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) all(is.na(df[x,c("a1","a2","a3")])))
```

But I'm looking for something faster.

I thought using `dplyr::mutate` might be a good solution but:

```
> df %>% dplyr::mutate(all(is.na(c(a1,a2,a3))))
  a0   a1   a2 a3 all(is.na(c(a1, a2, a3)))
1  1    A    a NA                     FALSE
2  2    B <NA> NA                     FALSE
3  3 <NA> <NA> NA                     FALSE
```

Doesn't give me the desired outcome.

Any idea how to get `dplyr::mutate` to give:

```
df$all.na <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

On this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `rowwise` with `do`

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("a1","a2","a3")

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do( (.) %>% as.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(all.na = all(is.na(.[cols]))))

#     a0 a1    a2    a3    all.na
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> 
#1     1 A     a     NA    FALSE 
#2     2 B     NA    NA    FALSE 
#3     3 NA    NA    NA    TRUE
```

---

Or a more general approach using `tidyverse` `gather` and `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -a0) %>%
  group_by(a0) %>%
  mutate(all.na = all(is.na(value))) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

---

However, in base R there is a better approach using `is.na` and `rowSums`

```
df$all.na <- rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) == length(cols)

df
#  a0   a1   a2 a3 all.na
#1  1    A    a NA  FALSE
#2  2    B <NA> NA  FALSE
#3  3 <NA> <NA> NA   TRUE
```

---

This can also be achieved using `apply` row-wise (`MARGIN = 1`) but this will not help with any speed improvements.

```
df$all.na <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` making use of `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
     mutate(all.na = pmap_lgl(.[cols], ~ all(is.na(c(...))))) 
#   a0   a1   a2 a3 all.na
#1  1    A    a NA  FALSE
#2  2    B <NA> NA  FALSE
#3  3 <NA> <NA> NA   TRUE
```

---

Or another option is to convert to logical vector with `map` and `reduce` it back to a single logical `vector`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(all.na = map(.[cols], is.na) %>%
         reduce(`&`))
```

---

With `base R`, this can be achieved using `Reduce` and `lapply`

```
df$all.na <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(df[cols], is.na))
```

#### data

```
cols <- c("a1","a2","a3")
```